# Spark Submit a pyspark file with a JAR dependency

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark code in a file, let's call it somePythonSQL.py
I am trying to submit this to Spark using an ojdbc.jar dependency because the pysaprk actually connects to an oracle database.
spark-submit  --master yarn somePythonSQL.py --jars "/home/ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar"

But I get:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o45.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

How can I submit the jar dependency.
It works fine in interactive (REPL?) mode.i.e.

```
pyspark --jars "/home/ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar" --master yarn
```

Then at the >>> prompt, type the python commands and it works.
But spark-submit does not.

Answer (score 0):

Python script should be the last argument

```sh
spark-submit --master yarn --jars "/home/ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar" somePythonSQL.py
```